# I am building a survey application using bootstrap,in that i have two image buttons thumbs up(likeq1()) and thumbs down(unlikeq1()) button

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a survey application using bootstrap,in that i have two image buttons thumbs up and thumbs down on my page , when i click thumbs up button it should be selected and when i click on thumbs down button it should select this button but deselect the thumbs up button.and also want to validate that the user must select a button without selecting it should not process or navigate to other page.

My code for the button :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10" align="left">
        <h5> My products solve real world problems.</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <h4><button type="button" class="btn-link" value="0" id="like1" onclick="likeq1()" >
        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up" ></span>
       </button></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <h4> <button type="button" class="btn-link" value="0" id="unlike1" align="right" onclick="unlikeq1()">
        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-down" ></span>
        </button></h4>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the code for button?

Comment: Edit the question to show `likeq1()` and `unlikeq1`